# Threaded clock object

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a threaded "clock" which all the other objects can see. Every time period corresponding to a tick of the clock ,the clock would increment a counter. It would then provide a public method for other classes to read the current time . 1 tick represents 5 seconds of simulated time, but takes only 1 second. Here's what i implemented until now:

```
  public class Clock extends Thread

{
    private int seconds = 0;


    public void run()
    {
        //sleep 1000 mil secs
        this.seconds += 5;
    }



}
```

I would like to receive some feedback on the method that would provide the current time to other classes. And here is an example of what i did until now on another class that will use the method:

```
public class Entry extends Thread
{

    Clock c;

    public Entry(Clock clock)
    {

        c = clock;
    }
```

Comment: Tell us about the problem you are trying to solve. Knowing what you want to achieve helps us give better answers.

Comment: The entry class will produce car objects,so i want every time a car enters the town to give it a timestamp of the current time.

Comment: Need for timer thread seems pointless and error prone. Instead, record the start time of your program, get a difference to that and multiply it by five. You can provide the time from a static method of a utility class.

Comment: why don't you use System.currenttimeMillis() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `seconds` field `volatile` (this is the bare minimum sync. primitive that you can use).The reason is that the compiler may cache this field in a local register otherwise, and the other threads reading this variable may read a stale value.

This is a good example of why you need to sync. your state even when there's only concurrent reading and no concurrent writing.

Edit: As others have mentioned, your design is bad.

Answer (score 0):

This design might be fine, or it might be broken, but it all depends on details that we can't see from here including the rest of your code and what you are trying to achieve.

I would consider:

- You will likely need to make the time a bit more thread-safe, e.g. mark it `volatile` or maybe access it in a `synchronized` block (such as a `synchronized` getter method)
- Rather than a spin loop inside "`Clock.run`", you could perhaps multiply `System.currenttimeMillis()` by 5, but it rather depends on what you are trying to achieve

I don't think this question really works on Stackoverflow -- there isn't a single correct answer yet.

I think your code is a decent enough start. Why not just try this approach and see how you get on, then update it in light of your experience? You will probably get further faster by doing that than by trying to design it on here.